# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy - ReasonPhrase: Forbidden

Tags: maven, deployment

I am getting the follwoing error when doing deploy onmy project in IJ:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project aaf-freedom-landing-zone: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact YYYYYY from/to ZZZZZ (http://XXXXXXX/artifactory/libs-release-local): Access denied to: XXXXXXX/artifactory/libs-release-local/landing-zone-1.0.0.0-SNAPHOT.jar, ReasonPhrase: Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>

    </parent>

    <artifactId>landing-zone</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0-SNAPHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <description>AAF project for Freedom Landing Zone</description>
    <name>Landing-Zone</name>
    <properties>
        <infra.version>2.2.10</infra.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbehave/jbehave-core -->
        <!--${infra.version}-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<systemPropertyVariables>-->
                        <!--<environment>AAF</environment>-->
                    <!--</systemPropertyVariables>-->
                    <!--<suiteXmlFiles>-->
                        <!--<suiteXmlFile>src\main\resources\testSuites\FirstSuite_S3Buckets.xml</suiteXmlFile>-->
                    <!--</suiteXmlFiles>-->
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>aaf-freedom-Landing-Zone</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>
                            src/main/resources/assembly.xml
                        </descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>
                                single
                            </goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```